# Meaning of this passage

Tags: word-usage

What is the meaning of the bolded part:

> He stepped out beneath the arched doorway, past the children playing, past the elevators, until the shenai quieted. **He had forgotten what it was like to move through a crowd feeling like a hypocrite among them, aware of the scrutinizing gaze of his father, expecting Amar to embarrass him, anticipating t**he lie he would tell before he even spoke.

Comment: I have no idea why this should be closed. The sentence quoted is very poorly drafted and so obscure. A learner may legitimately find it perplexing.

Comment: @JeffM - I can see a couple reasons why it should be put on hold. For one, the OP should [tell us where the text was found](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084). For another, it should include more [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) about what is confusing. Is the OP having trouble with big words, like _scrutinizing_ and _hypocrite_? Or is it the lengthiness of the sentence that is causing confusion?

Comment: @JR I am a native English speaker who has spent a large part of my professional life writing. Even I am not sure what was really intended by that text. Although you are correct **in general** that details about what exactly a reader finds obscure are desirable, I feel we defeat our purpose when we ask for specifics about what is obscure within the incoherent. For example, does "anticipating" relate to the father or son and which of the two is expected to lie. Competent writers do not flit between differents referents of the same pronoun while indulging in two dangling modifiers in succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not well written, with dangling modifiers, inconsistent tenses, etc. It probably means something like:

> He had forgotten how the surrounding crowd made him realize that it would view him as a hypocrite. Moreover, he was aware of the scrutiny of his father, who anticipated, even before Amar opened his mouth, that he would be an embarrassment or would lie.

I cannot be sure that is what was intended. Not every published author writes comprehensible prose. If it is a translation, the fault may lie with either the author or the translator, or perhaps both are partially at fault.